# GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog is null

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I'm using ACRA ([arca.ch](http://acra.ch)) to generate automatic error reports.

I just released a new version of my app using Google Maps Android API v2.  I'm getting an error reported by EEEPad and Transformer Pad users when trying to show the dialog returned by GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog.  Does anyone know why this might happen?

Here is the relevant code and Logcat as reported by acra:

While calling this line:

```
int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
{
        //The dialog that comes back is null (probably due to the logcat message)
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 69);
        //So when I call the next line, the app crashes with a NullPointerException
        dialog.show();
}
...
```

Logcat:

```
12-18 04:21:04.531 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3977): Google Play Store signature invalid.
12-18 04:21:04.551 E/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3977): Google Play services is invalid. Cannot recover.
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

**Update**

The issue has not been resolved by google yet and I will update this question once I hear anything (see CommonsWare's answer for the Google Bug report link).  In the mean time if you come across this issue and don't want your app to crash, here's what I'm doing for the time being:

```
public void checkGooglePlayServicesAvailability()
{
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 69);
        if(dialog != null)
        {
            dialog.show();                
        }
        else
        {
            showOkDialogWithText(this, "Something went wrong. Please make sure that you have the Play Store installed and that you are connected to the internet. Contact developer with details if this persists.");
        }
    }

    Log.d("GooglePlayServicesUtil Check", "Result is: " + resultCode);
}

public static void showOkDialogWithText(Context context, String messageText)
{
    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(messageText);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi DiscDev, When I try to use showOkDialogWithText() it's throwing error saying that "can't create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare()" why it's trying to run on worker thread instead of UI thread?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Google [suggests](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) (also in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html)) calling `getErrorDialog()` if the result code is `SERVICE_MISSING`, `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` or `SERVICE_DISABLED`. So it may be that the last possible status code (`SERVICE_INVALID`) is what's causing trouble.

I'm using the following code and so far it seems to work ok (testing in emulator, platform 2.3.3):

```
int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity.getApplicationContext());
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    activity.selectMap();
} else if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING ||
           resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED ||
           resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED) {
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity, 1);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I just tested `getErrorDialog` with `ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID` and got `null` on my Nexus S. So I suppose this answer is correct.

Comment: So, you are ignoring SERVICE_INVALID all together? Shouldn't this be handled as well?

Comment: One should use **GoogleApiAvailability**, not **GooglePlayServicesUtil**.

Answer (score 22):

Seems like you have to check with `isUserRecoverableError` before trying to display the dialog.

```
  int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
  if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
      GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 
      REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported.", 
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      finish();
    }
  }
```

Comment: +1 - GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status) is more elegant than enumerating through all possible states.

Comment: +1 - I'm using this now, but after reading this question I think I'll also check for null, since it's an easy check to add.

Answer (score 8):

Based on Rahim's code, I add the capability of preventing the user to dismiss the Google Play Services dialog (by hitting the back button) and continue using the app without Google Play Services installed:

```
private void checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0);
            dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An update of the answer by [@Nevermore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1948704/nevermore), since `GooglePlayServicesUtil` methods are deprecated in favour of `GoogleApiAvailability`:

```
GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity.getApplicationContext());
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    activity.selectMap();
} else if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING ||
           resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED ||
           resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED) {
    Dialog dialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, resultCode, 1);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Note the order of the first two parameters in `getErrorDialog()` has been switched around in the `GoogleApiAvailability` implementation.