# Google Maps Android API v2 - Google Play Store is missing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

In the newly published version of my app that is using Google Maps Android API V2, I've implemented all the things suggested by the developer guides to ensure the user has GooglePlayServices installed, and it has been working well on all the devices I own and the several hundred people that have updated to the new version of the app so far.

Today I received a bug report via [acra](http://acra.ch) with a strange error.  This is happening on the following line of code, after setupMapIfNeeded() has completed:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Logcat reports:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(10401): Google Play Store is missing.
```

Shouldn't the call to GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() also ensure that the Play Store is installed?  That seems like a huge oversight on Google's part if it doesn't.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get OS version info from ACRA?  I have heard of problems with Google play when people install custom ROMs.  Could be someone messing with their device.

Comment: Hi iagreen - yes, I have that information.  My theory was also that they are using a ROM, but I am unaware how to determine that from the OS info.  Here it is:
PHONE_MODEL = Nexus S 4G

BRAND = google

PRODUCT = sojus

ANDROID_VERSION = '4.1.1

BUILD = BOARD=herring
BOOTLOADER=D720SPRLC1
BRAND=google
CPU_ABI=armeabi-v7a
CPU_ABI2=armeabi
DEVICE=crespo4g
DISPLAY=JRO03R
FINGERPRINT=google/sojus/crespo4g:4.1.1/JRO03R/438695:user/release-keys
HARDWARE=herring
HOST=vpba9.mtv.corp.google.com
ID=JRO03R
MANUFACTURER=samsung
MODEL=Nexus S 4G

I read that Nexus S 4G is officially on 4.1.1 since September

Comment: That looks like an official build (the build HOST is @ corp.google.com). I would still suspect a device configuration issue, unless you are getting lots of these reports.

Comment: Nope, just this one report so far, but I have seen several other weird things going on with GooglePlayServicesUtil (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932474/googleplayservicesutil-geterrordialog-is-null).  I thought it looked official as well.  It's odd to me they are able to download my app from the Play Store, then get this error when GooglePlayServicesUtil is invoked.  Hopefully someone with knowledge of the inner-workings of GooglePlayServicesUtil comes across this post eventually and enlightens us as to why this situation might happen.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone came here by accident or was just wondering why it was not working...

This could happen when user had old Android Market installed, which was replaced by Google Play Store.

Here is relevant issue: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4862 (fixed in february update).