# Android: Google Analytics availability in Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

Google Analytics has been announced to become part of the rolling out Google Play Services 4.3, however it is not yet included in the Google Play Services packages list:

http://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html

Any idea when it will become available, and will it be safe to be used straight away, or will it be better to wait for some time to make sure every user has Google Play Services 4.3 already installed?

Answer (score 37):

I've noticed some other differences.

**Tracker**

To get a new `Tracker`, use the `newTracker()` method (accepts both a `String` value and an `int` value [for XML configuration]):

```
googleTracker = gaInstance.getTracker(GA_KEY); // OLD
googleTracker = gaInstance.newTracker(GA_KEY); // NEW
```

**EasyTracker**

EasyTracker has now disappeared, so we will have to use `GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this)` as reported by *Paito*.

**Setters**

The `googleTracker.set()` method is no longer available. It has been replaced with more specialised methods, for example:

```
googleTracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, null); // OLD
googleTracker.setScreenName(null);           // NEW
```

**Event creation**

The `googleTracker.send()` method has also seen some changes.

```
googleTracker.send(MapBuilder
                .createEvent(category, action, label, value)
                .build()); // OLD
googleTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                .setCategory(category)
                .setAction(action)
                .setLabel(label)
                .setValue(value)
                .build()); // NEW
```

**AppView**

It now becomes

```
googleTracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());       // OLD
googleTracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build()); // NEW
```

**AppViewBuilder**

`AppViewBuilder` has now been deprecated, replaced by the new `ScreenViewBuilder` class. (*thanks Hai Phong for the tip!*)

---

For those who are running into (or have already dealt with) the **Dalvik's 64K methods limit**, there are now 3K methods that you will be able to get rid of in your application, thanks to this integration.

Comment: Do you know how to pass configuration to GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this) ? I  can't find out how to set ga_trackingId forexample

Comment: If you mean passing an XML configuration, the `newTracker()` also accepts an `int` parameter for the `configResId`. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#newTracker(int)

Comment: With EasyTracker I was able to just call it onStart and onStop. What I am trying to figure it out what do I call before GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this) to pass my config to instance of GoogleAnalytics

Comment: There is no example about setting config file for GoogleAnalytics but Tracker instance

Comment: I guess nothing has changed for that. So you keep using `GoogleAnalytics gaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());`

Comment: I had analytics.xml in values folder for v3 but v4 doesn;t seem to read it, I don't see any dispatch log (set to verbose logging)

Comment: Check the **3. Create a configuration XML file** point of this guide, maybe you need to update your analytics.xml file: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: Checked it. Still same. Thanks for your time anyway

Comment: Well, samples doesnlt say but you need to add this to AndroidManifest  <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
     android:resource="@xml/analytics_global_config" />

Comment: It should be a child of the <application> tag.

Comment: `AppViewBuilder` has been deprecated in favor of the new `ScreenViewBuilder` class

Comment: @dextor how do you associate a screenview with a particular event?

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the package list now.

I think the basic functionality works something like this...

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
}
```

Comment: thanks for notifying! any idea when it will be safe to use it?

Comment: You can use it now, just bump your Play Services version to 4.3. https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/bjPMhDMpM48

Comment: great! thanks! it looks like the Play Services 4.3 rollout is complete worldwide!

Comment: I think they still have to update the Google Analytics page. The Google Play Services 4.3 page (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html#newfeatures) links to this Google Analytics page (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/), where they still mention to install the jar in "Before you begin"

Comment: What happens if the app is installed on a device with no Google Play Services?

Comment: @MarkCarter, the big majority of the users already have Google Play Services 4.3 installed. However you can make sure users that don't have it would download it before using your app. In the `onStart()` of your main activity you can call this function I posted yesterday:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932474/googleplayservicesutil-geterrordialog-is-null/22651625#22651625

Comment: @Daniele B Thanks but in China the majority of users do not have Google Play Services at all. It is important to have a simple way to still provide analytics for those cases.

Comment: Yes, surely depends on the type of app you are releasing.

Comment: Yes, if you decide the analytics must be running regardless of whether Play Services 4.3 is installed, then you'll need to build a wrapper :(

Comment: To answer my own question, GA SDK v4 also works when Google Play Services is not installed :)

Answer (score 1):

As per conversation in order to use Easytracker replacement with

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
```

You need to add your config to AndroidManifest like

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource" android:resource="@xml/analytics_global_config" />
```

I'm still having to get instance of Tracker to send Events, may be somebody else would have better luck at replacing

```
 EasyTracker.getInstance(mContext).send(MapBuilder....)
```

Comment: I still get the error message "The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included." but after I added this meta-data to my AndroidManifest then Google Analytics started tracking properly.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Google Analytics SDK v4 (now part of Google Play Services) has just been published!

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/