# Android.Gms.Analytics.HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder is obsolete

Tags: android, google-analytics, xamarin, xamarin.android

When compiling our xamarin droid app we are getting the following warning:

```
'Android.Gms.Analytics.HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder' is obsolete: 'This class is obsoleted in this android platform'
```

We are using the latest version of Google play services for ICS and our app is running on API level 16. If the AppViewBuilder is obsolete what are we meant to use instead? or is there a new library we need to upgrade to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppViewBuilder has now been deprecated, replaced by the new ScreenViewBuilder class.
You can see more here [Android: Google Analytics availability in Google Play Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611295/android-google-analytics-availability-in-google-play-services)