# How to implement getErrorDialog in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, missing-features

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932474/googleplayservicesutil-geterrordialog-is-null), I am trying to implemet the getErrorDialog. I understand to everything in the code, *but* I copied and pasted the code above and I get errors in my script as I was missing a using. For example `GoogleApiAvailability does not exist in the context`. I can not add any using or so to fix the problems.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Hi, Can you add your code and why do you want a error dialog? I don't get the point of implementing that on Unity. You just cant show a panel on Unity upon receiving an error, right?

Comment: Hi, I am using Google Play Games Plugin to sign into my game. I am getting errors when users try to run my game and do not have Play Games installed or updated.

Comment: Ok, got the idea. However, as a general programming standard you should try to decouple your program/game from outside elements. This being said you should get the response that is handled in your unity project. You shouldn't reinvent the wheel because that when is your product gets complicated. The easiest solution I can think of is: handling that error within your unity game and display a message. Also, you shouldn't "require" having other applications installed to run your game. That is not a good use case.

Comment: But play games plugin in Unity require to have it installed. Many apps requiere that. That is not from my mind :-) I just need to fix this problem. But as soon as I write GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
GoogleApiAvailability just does not exist.